# How to Iterate through directory, ordered based on the file time

Tags: go, directory, iteration, directory-structure

Go provides a directory iteration functionality out of the box,  with `filepath.Walk` in the `path/filepath` package.

However, `filepath.Walk` [walks the file tree in lexical order](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Walk). How can I walks the file tree in the order of last-modified date? Thx

**PS** (after accepting the answer) I think the Go `filepath.Walk` function should provide a way for people to provide the sorting themselves, like the following answer, in which accepting `type ByModTime` is all it take for people to sort the files themselves themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, you should implement it by yourself, because `filepath.Walk` doesn't allow you to set order.

Look at [Walk](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/34b455da4484dee20e8c355b50d24680224b58f2/src/path/filepath/path.go#L393) method. It calls [walk](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/34b455da4484dee20e8c355b50d24680224b58f2/src/path/filepath/path.go#L350), which is relying on file names from [readDirNames](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/34b455da4484dee20e8c355b50d24680224b58f2/src/path/filepath/path.go#L408). So basically, you should make your own `Walk` method with another `readDirNames` logic.

Here's how you get files in the order of last-modified date (note, that I'm ignoring errors):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sort"
)

type ByModTime []os.FileInfo

func (fis ByModTime) Len() int {
    return len(fis)
}

func (fis ByModTime) Swap(i, j int) {
    fis[i], fis[j] = fis[j], fis[i]
}

func (fis ByModTime) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return fis[i].ModTime().Before(fis[j].ModTime())
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Open("/")
    fis, _ := f.Readdir(-1)
    f.Close()
    sort.Sort(ByModTime(fis))

    for _, fi := range fis {
        fmt.Println(fi.Name())
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo! You've made it more simpler than I thought! Thanks!

Comment: Excellent Implementation~